# how to use existing Sip Stack libraries in android application?

Tags: android, sip

i am developing a one SIP application to simply make and receive a call. for that propose i have to add existing SIP stack libraries to support SIP calling. many sip stack libraries are available in open source like [mjsip](http://mjsip.org/mjua.html),[doubango](http://www.doubango.org/) etc. but my question is how to implement that libraries in our application?

i want to develop my application which can be supported in Android 2.3.3 and higher than that versions.

Android 2.3.3 supports SIP but i am facing the problem that is my application only works on wi-fi network. in 3G,GPRS and EDGE networks its not working.thats the reason i want to use external **sipstack** libraries. is there any good example or tutorial for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at open source projects that already did it:

- [CSipSample](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/)
- [SipDroid](http://sipdroid.org/)

Comment: thanks but  i have already looked at SipDroid project but i cant understand the implementation of Sip libraries. i mean should i import the package of SIP libraies(MjSip or Dobango) and then use its methods? or is there any other way of implemetation?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you don't understand? Is it JNI? The way the sources are organized in the project?

Comment: JNI is the layer between Java code and native code (C, C++). It rely on the native keyword and static methods. In your app, you will use only Java methods and classes. You will need to compile the C/C++ sources to a dynamic library, a .so file. That is why you see C source code and makefiles in AipDroid and CSipSimple.